# Remapping keycode generated by a mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, xinput

I have a Logitech T400 mouse which has a button that generates a keycode Super_L like a keyboard. xev results of presses (from a keyboard and mouse button) are exactly same (see below). Is there any way to filter the key press from a specific device and remap regular middle click to it ?

More Details :

```
$ xinput 
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
- Logitech T400                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
- Logitech T400                             id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]

$xinput test 22
key press   133 
key release 133
```

I am pressing that mouse button in the "xinput test".  I want to filter keycode 133 from virtual keyboard 22 and want to remap a regular middle-click to it, but not the ones coming from the other devices. Any suggestions ?

thanks.
ilker.

Comment: I'm not sure so I'll leave this as a comment rather than an answer — you might be able to do this using the [`libratbag` tools](https://github.com/libratbag) (in particular, `ratbagctl` in the `ratbagd` project). You might need to add your device ids to the hardware database.

Comment: Thanks for pointing libratbag but I couldn't make them work. I guess there is no easy way to achieve this. My workaround is removing modifier Super_L and making it a regular key. Then mapping it to whatever I want. However that changes it for all the input devices....